# Read xml data with namespaces from SQLite database in C#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, sqlite

I'm confronted with a XML structure from a SQLite database with two namespaces. How can I reference to 'floatnumber' (behind second ns) when no attribute name is present?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<anyType xmlns:q1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         d1p1:type="q1:string" 
         xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   floatnumber
 </anyType>
```

Connecting with package v1.0.98.0 from https://system.data.sqlite.org/ to SQLite database was straight forward. I was playin around with XmlReader and XDocument (LINQ-to-XML) but no success.

What is the best way to read 'floatnumber' (database column 'Value') from xml in C# ?

```
using (SQLiteCommand sqlcmd = new SQLiteCommand())
{
    sqlcmd.Connection = connect;
    sqlcmd.CommandText = sqlquery;
    SQLiteDataReader rdr = null;
    try
    {
        rdr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
        while (rdr.Read())
        {
            string xmlstr = rdr["Value"].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(xmlstr);                  // gives whole xml structure

            /* code to get floatnumber from xml */
        }
    }
    catch ()
    {}
}
```

My first post here.
Tom

Answer (score 0):

From the provided XML `anyType` does **NOT** have a namespace. It does define two namespaces `q1` and `d1p1` but they are not used to reference the element.  The sample below uses an [XPath expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) to get the element.  You could also use [Linq to XML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx).

```
Using System.Xml;

var doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstr);
var floatnumber = doc.SelectSingleNode("anyType[content() = 'floatnumber']");
```

**Update**

```
string s = doc.SelectSingleNode("anyType").Value;
double d = XmlConvert.ToDouble(s);
```

Comment: Thank you Rich, "but anyType[content() = 'floatnumber']" will not work since 'floatnumber' is always occupied by a numeric number which presents the size of a SharePoint backup in kByte. Sorry, may be I described that element not sufficiently.

Comment: NullReferenceException while converting string to double, because 's' IsNullOrEmpty.

Answer (score 0):

Using XML Linq

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xmlstr =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                "<anyType xmlns:q1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"" +
                      " d1p1:type=\"q1:string\"" +
                      " xmlns:d1p1=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">" +
                      "floatnumber" +
               "</anyType>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlstr);
            XElement anyType = (XElement)doc.FirstNode;
            XNamespace ns = anyType.Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace q1 = anyType.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "q1").FirstOrDefault().Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace type = anyType.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "type").FirstOrDefault().Name.Namespace;
            XNamespace d1p1 = anyType.Attributes().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "d1p1").FirstOrDefault().Name.Namespace;

            string floatnumber = anyType.Value;

        }
    }
}​
```